# Remove "---------" from model choice field with radio select widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button

In my `forms.py` I have this field below that returns 2 records, but it displays 3 records on my screen. I don't want the first one `"---------"`.

```
tipopagamento = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), queryset=tipopagamento.objects.all(), required=True)
```

My screen displays:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) to `None`.

```
tipopagamento = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
    queryset=tipopagamento.objects.all(),
    required=True,
    empty_label=None,
)
```